# How to install gcc-4.3 for NS2

Tags: gcc, ns2

I want to install NS2 in Ubuntu.

I run the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev gcc-4.3
```

But I got an error:

```
Package gcc-4.3 is not available
.
.
.
E: Package 'gcc-4.3' has no installation candidate.
```

Could you please provide me how to install gcc-4.3 [Step-by-Step]??

Comment: Try with gcc-4.4

Answer (score 2):

Install the metapackage `gcc`. This will automatically install the latest available version of gcc, so you won't need to worry about the details. If you need an outdated version for this particular program to build, `gcc-4.4` is the oldest you can get through the package manager.

To clarify, that's `sudo apt-get install gcc` or `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4`

I'm not aware of any archives that have the particular 4.3 release that you're looking for. I am assuming that any version will work just as well, and that NS2 merely provided old build instructions.

Comment: down vote accept
 

Thanks for your support.I run that command and get the below message:

gcc is already the newest version.

actually I am trying to install NS2 by following up the steps of below article:

http://www.whackk.com/april-2011/how-installing-ns-234-ubuntu-1010?page=1

But, when I apply step#5 I got a message:

Package gcc-4.3 is not available . . . E: Package 'gcc-4.3' has no installation candidate.

How I can solve this error?

Comment: I still think the latest version would work, but I decided to try answering your actual question and I discovered this website which provides old GCC versions: http://gcc-uk.internet.bs/releases/ I downloaded one, and it had HTML installation instructions in it.